# On diagonal terms in the Coulomb matrix

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

I have seen many machine learning algorithms for prediction of quantum chemistry properties that use Coulomb matrix as their input. Coulomb matrix is defined as

$$\boldsymbol{M}_{i j}^{\mathrm{Coulomb}}=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}{0.5 Z_{i}^{2.4}} & {\text { for } i=j} \\ {\frac{Z_{i} Z_{j}}{R_{i j}}} & {\text { for } i \neq j}\end{array}\right.$$

where the diagonal terms:

> ... can be seen as the interaction of an atom with itself and are
>   essentially a polynomial fit of the atomic energies to the nuclear
>   charge.

I was trying to read more about these diagonal terms and how exactly this equation is fitted. It seems that the model was first utilized by [Rupp et al Phys. Rev. Lett.,108(5):058301, 2012](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.058301), but there is not much more than this one sentence there. Essentially, I'm looking for something that says: ". . . and from there we get $0.5Z^{2.4}$" and if these energies can be extended to bonds as well, as the off-diagonal term in Coulomb matrix represent repulsion forces rather than potentials. Any references would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about machine learning algorithms for quantum chemistry, however it is easy to guess what that $0.5 Z^{2.4}$ term means: it is an approximation to the total energy of atoms. 
Consider, for example, the following ground-state energies of neutral atoms computed at the Dirac-Hartree-Fock level:
*L. Visscher and K.G. Dyall, Dirac-Fock atomic electronic structure calculations using different nuclear charge distributions, Atom. Data Nucl. Data Tabl., 67, (1997), 207.*
Data are available as Table II at 
http://dirac.chem.sdu.dk/doc/FiniteNuclei/FiniteNuclei.shtml

A fit of those energies (using the values computed with a point-charge nucleus) to a functional form of the type $E=0.5 Z^\alpha$ for $Z=1$ to $Z=109$ results (my calculations) in $\alpha =2.42$, and the typical fitting error is about 3%. In all probability the constant is fixed to $0.5$ to reproduce exactly the energy of the hydrogen atom.